# unique key prop error even with unique key on table row

Tags: reactjs

I am not sure how to correct this issue. I am using a unique ID but react still isn't happy. I tried to do it on each  but then it complains about duplicates.

```
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {!loading &&
                products &&
                products.map((product) => (
                  <>
                    <tr>
                      <td key={product._id}>{product.name}</td>
                      <td>
                        <span>
                          <strong>{product.desc}</strong>
                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </>
                ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the key in the upper most component: the Fragment. So instead of `<>` use `<React.Fragment key={...}>`

Answer (score 1):

or instead of handling the key by yourself, maybe let React handle it for you. I find it pretty handy:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {
      !loading && products && React.Children.toArray(
        products.map((product) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{product.name}</td>
            <td>
              <span>
                <strong>{product.desc}</strong>
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))
      )
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

so you'll never have to worry about assigning keys anymore!

---

**React.Children.toArray**

Returns the children opaque data structure as a flat array with keys assigned to each child. Useful if you want to manipulate collections of children in your render methods, especially if you want to reorder or slice this.props.children before passing it down.

> Official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray